# How to make two weeks date_trunk in SQL (Vertica)?

Tags: sql, timestamp, vertica, sql-timestamp

I need to turn each timestamp to its date_trunk with two weeks interval. Say, same as `date_trunk('week', event_time)`, but it would be `date_trunk('2 weeks', event_time)`. So I'd have a timestamp column, and its two-weeks date_trunk column as following.

I tried going with `date_trunc('week', event_time) + '1 week'::interval` or  `date_trunc('week', event_time) +7` but it just makes an offset from my event_date.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: How are you defining a two-week interval here?  Just as for single year-weeks, a year-2-week may vary from year to year.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I mean the same way as it works with date_trunk(week): yes it will vary, but I have only one-year date, so its not a problem. So if before days 1-7 of a month were Week 1, days 8-14 were Week 2 (if day 1 is Monday), so in the case I'm looking for days 1-14 would be "Week1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that ISO week #1 and #2 should map to 2-week #1, weeks 3 and 4 map to 2-week #2 etc.  We can try using floor and division here:

```
SELECT
    event_time,
    FLOOR((WEEK(event_time) + 1) / 2) AS two_week
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: It seems like Vertica doesn't support timestamp / int :( I tried extract(EPOCH FROM(DATE_TRUNC('week', event_time) - 1)) / 2 , but the output is not a date anymore...

Comment: @Polly Use `WEEK` to obtain the week year from your event date.  I don't use Vertica FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` expression:

```
select (case when mod(week(event_time), 1)
             then date_trunc('week', event_time)
             else date_trunc('week', event_time) - interval '1 week'
        end)
```

Comment: but as I see, it does the same as date_trunc('week', event_time) - 7, with I already did :) So actually its the same one week interval, not two as I'm looking for.

Comment: @Polly . . . Not at all.  This only does the subtract on even-numbered weeks.  Do you understand how `case` and `mod` work?

Answer (score 0):

So my final code actually is (with a help of @Tim Biegeleisen):

```
select distinct 
            event_date 
          , min(event_date) over (partition by two_week) as two_week
        from (
            select distinct 
                event_time::date as event_date
                , FLOOR(week((DATE_TRUNC('week', event_time) - 1)) / 2) AS two_week
            from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of my favourite Vertica-specific functions on date / time: `TIME_SLICE()` .

```
SELECT
  dt
, TIME_SLICE(dt,24*7*2,'HOUR') AS hebdo
FROM dt;
```

The biggest unit is the hour, but you can multiply it ....